# Best Way to use maps In Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

In the documentation it says that using the map control in windows phone 8.0 is obsellete using this method. But I could not find how to implement the api maps in windows phone 8.0 silverlight?

```
<maps:Map x:Name="bingMap" >
   <maps:Map.Center>
      <Location:GeoCoordinate Altitude="NaN"
                              Course="NaN"HorizontalAccuracy="NaN"                                  
                              Longitude="-2.922363" 
                              Latitude="54.6128" 
                              Speed="NaN" 
                              VerticalAccuracy="NaN"/>
   </maps:Map.Center>
 </maps:Map>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide the namespace from your code?

I'm currently developing a Windows Phone 8 Silverlight app and I'm using this one:

`xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps"`

Besides, I've only found this note in Msdn documentation, but it is about another Map API:

"The new Maps API in Windows Phone 8 is different from the Bing Maps available in Windows Phone OS 7.1. The Bing Maps control is still supported in Windows Phone 8, but is deprecated. Typically, the only time you should use the Bing Maps control is in an existing app that you have upgraded from Windows Phone OS 7.1 to Windows Phone 8."

Comment: @mm_Dev please see above article

Answer (score 0):

I have since found this excellent article thanks to the team of msdn about using the new maps bing api.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bingdevcenter/archive/2014/06/24/using-maps-in-universal-apps.aspx